# C# Possible lambda in array's content declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, function, lambda

I have such piece of code:

```
    string suffix = "wallpapers\\";
    string extenstion = ".jpg";
    string[] wallpapers;

    .....
    void SetWallPapers()
    {
        wallpapers = new string[] {
            suffix + "1" + extenstion,
            suffix + "2" + extenstion,
            suffix + "3" + extenstion,
            suffix + "4" + extenstion,
        };
    }
```

Is there any variant to make lambda-declaretion in array content like:

( pseudo-code, idea only! )

```
wallpapers = new string[] { ( () => { for i = 1 till 4 -> suffix + i + extension; } ) }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A 'suffix' is something you add to the end of something, you might want to change it to 'prefix' (or maybe 'path' in this case).

Comment: @Joe , no I don't, but now have, thanks to all :)

Comment: I'm constantly amazed by how many people can give an [almost] identical answer.

Comment: @Joe they all are different in a ways how to format string of image-path

Comment: Yes. All different techniques for joining a string together with an identical outcome. Some are better practise than others but still, lots of duplicates. This happens a lot on StackOverflow, I never know why. I always upvote the first correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string template = "wallpapers\\{0}.jpg";

string[] wallpapers =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
        .Select(i => string.Format(template, i))
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] wallpapers = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
                                .Select(i => suffix + i + extenstion)
                                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Linq like so:

```
wallpapers =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
    .Select(i => String.Concat(suffix, i, extenstion))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(a => "string" + a).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. If you're ok with generating your array at runtime, use

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(i => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", suffix, i, extension)).ToArray();
```

PS Your code can't work anyway, you can't add `int` to `string`.